# WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document error with Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, toctree, numpydoc

I used the `sphinx-quickstart` to set everything up. I used `doc/` for the documentation root location. The folder containing my package is setup as:

```
myfolder/
    doc/
    mypackage/
        __init__.py
        moprob.py
        ...
```

After the quick start, I edited the path in `conf.py` to be:

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
```

Then I added one of the scripts in my package to `index.rst` to see how Sphinx works.

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:
   
   mypackage/moprob
```

The error code I get:

> `.../index.rst:9: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document u'mypackage/moprob'`

Solutions I have tried:

1. Adding `sphinx.ext.napoleon` to the extensions list since all of my doc strings are written using the NumPy format. The error did not go away. I also put the napoleon extension after autodoc because one of the documentation pages suggested that.

   ```py
   extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc',
   'sphinx.ext.napoleon']
   ```
2. Adding `numpydoc_show_class_members = False` to `conf.py`. I put this directly below the extensions but it also did not solve the error.
3. A couple of different configurations for folder locations. I've also tried setting the root location to be `/myfolder` and setting the source to be `/mypackage` and the build to be `/doc`. None has worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [toctree](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html) directive contains references to reStructuredText documents, not Python scripts or modules. Sphinx expects there to be a **mypackage/moprob.rst** file (in the **doc** folder), but there isn't one. Hence the error.

To quickly get some meaningful output, create the mypackage/moprob.rst file. Add a heading and an [automodule](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#directive-automodule) directive in it:

```
moprob module
=============

.. automodule:: mypackage.moprob
   :members:
```

Then run sphinx-build again.